# How to insert a link, which opens the URL by JS code instead following the URL directly?

Tags: javascript, html

I intend to insert a web link to page, which doesn't follow the URL, but runs a JS function instead, which opens the URL in different browser. So far I have made this basic framework

```
var btn = document.createElement('a');
btn.setAttribute('href', url);
btn.setAttribute('_target', 'blank'); // here I need something like _null or _void
btn.textContent = 'Find the item externally';
var ref = document.evaluate('/div[@class="seaarch-form"]/div[@class="submit_button"]', node, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var btnNode = node.insertBefore(btn, ref.singleNodeValue);
btnNode.addEventListener("click", search_external, false);
.
.
.
function search_external() {
  var url = this.href;
  //system('firefox ' + url); // not supported
}
```

First problem is, that the link still opens in the current browser. I wish the href is still valid, so that the link can be eg. copied to clipboard or drag&drop to other application. Perhaps the upcoming action could be stopped in search_external function, but I don't have idea how.

Second problem is that I don't have clue how to run shell command from userscript. Possibly this is disabled for security reason? Anyway there should be a differen way how to open the link in different browser, for example encode it into URI.